# I have a problem using a variable when modifying a css property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change a css property of a HTML element using Javascript. I can't find a solution to my problem. I would like to use the element with the id of CreateMenu, and apply the variable called value to the property specified by the type variable, but it doesn't seem to support variables.

edit: Type is the variable i want to use to get which property i want to edit.

```
function style(name, type, value) {
    document.getElementById("CreateMenu").style.type = value;
}
```

Comment: there is no style property called `.type` ... there may be one `[type]` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test the following but you can access an object property by its key name this way:

```
function style(name, type, value) {
    document.getElementById("CreateMenu").style[type] = value;
}
```

Comment: Mark my answer as correct, if it worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using object "dot" notation

```
document.getElementById("CreateMenu").style.type = value;
```

you're assigning to, literally `.style.type`

What you need to do in this case is use *bracket notation*

so

```
document.getElementById("CreateMenu").style[type] = value;
```